# Forge Properties - How to identify the collections returned

Tags: autodesk-forge

My platform calls the [properties endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) to get the mass, area, etc of an item. It is necessary at later points to recall this endpoint. When I do that, I need to be able to identify the body or component that I need. However, the only identifying parts of the collection returned at the name, an object id, and an "externalId".

Is the object id unique and unchanging? I believe that it is not and can depend upon the arrangement of the components and can be reassigned if an object is deleted, etc. I do not believe that the externalId is unique either for the bodies.

Is there any way to identify a body through something other than the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the object id unique and unchanging?

It's unique and constant for a given derivative after it's generated - but will be re-generated if the same model is translated again.

> Is there any way to identify a body through something other than the name?

Can do so by a component's `externalId` which is always consistent with the unique primary ID as in the model every time the derivatives are generated.